# uWSGI standalone mode, Symbol not found: _uwsgi_opt_corerouter

Tags: uwsgi

Try to run uWSGI in http standalone mode, config ini:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /Users/gino/Workspace/project
module = project.wsgi:application
home = /Users/gino/VirtualEnv/project
processes = 2
plugins = python, http
pidfile = /tmp/project.pid
http = 127.0.0.1:8080
```

This config will run django project in uwsgi.

I run command uwsgi --ini project.ini
I got this error:

```
    !!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/uwsgi/2.0.8/libexec/uwsgi/http_plugin.so, 10): 
      Symbol not found: _uwsgi_opt_corerouter
      Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/uwsgi/2.0.8/libexec/uwsgi/http_plugin.so
      Expected in: dynamic lookup
    !!!
```

So, I can't access `http://127.0.0.1:8080` in browser. If I use uwsgi with socket and use nginx as http server, it works well.

How can I fix it? Thanks.

System: Mac OS X 10.10
uWSGI: brew install uwsgi

Notice:If you install uwsgi by python pip, YOU SHOULD NOT meet this problem.

Comment: Try adding `corerouter` plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `plugins` entry.

The http server is embedded in uwsgi http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/HTTP.html

Python is not needed as plugin

See doc [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#deploying-django)

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but it doesn't work. If you install uwsgi using language specific ways like python pip, the relevant language is embedded, so you do not need to load the plugin. But I install it by brew, so I need to add plugins to make uwsgi to support python and http. If I remove python plugin, I can't visit it from nginx either.